# How to show 2 rows as 1 row in ssrs table?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I get data as below from dataset

```
   Year      custname               custnum   Jan   feb      Mar     Apr    May    Jun  
  2013  ABC Ability                 000104  199145  9299    1496     0       0       0      
  2012  ABC Ability                 000104  202940  10477   0        0       0       0
  2013  XYZ Receiv                  000110  81499   66667   94915   236830  102533  69619
  2012  XYZ Receiv                  000110  136948  94051   84563   69581   73565   68922
  2013  PQR Recoveries              000644  213872  172285  224032  227751  254794  212183 
  2012  PQR Recoveries              000644  247707  253114  302022  286795  327772  300033
```

I want to my report look like as

```
  Customer                           Jan     feb     mar    jan    apr     may     Jun
  ABC Ability                      199145   9299    14960   0       0       0
   000104                           000104  202940  10477   0       0       0       0
```

and so on for next customers and at the end the totals for each month different for each year

---

**Update**

I got the the data representing as required now only stuck at the totals

I want the totals sepratly for each year basis

That is at the end it should look like

```
   Total     this row will contain total for 2013 for each column
             this row will contain total for 2012 for each column
```

so i need to filter the dataset for yearly basis and get the total but don't know how any help would be great

Comment: Do you want to replace customer name on customer number if year = 2012?

Comment: I don't want to replace the customer name or anything i want to repeat the 2 years data for each customer in table first row contins 2013 years data 2nd row 2012 then goes to next customer and continues as above

Comment: @Konza actulay i got this functionality now only needed that can i get the total for each month for yearly seprated. I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
1. Insert the row outside the group below
2. Add new parent row group within the new row.
3. Add Year field from your dataset as your grouping element
4. When the new group is created go to properties of this group
5. Go to "Filters" tab and add new filter
6. In "expression" field choose Year, in "value" field insert value of "2012"
7. Repeat this for year 2013.
```

In design mode your report should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tested it and it worked, but i already got what i wanted with other way and workaround that was so much headache, this is simple and elegant i will updating my report with this solution. Thanks !